# Can the level of pain be measured?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, anatomy, brain

Because of a recent question I ended up reading through the [Painkill-discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/should-questions-about-painfully-killing-people-be-welcomed-on-this-site?noredirect=1&lq=1) on meta and in the linked question the_OTHER_DJMethaneMan wrote in a comment

> Is there a way to "rate" the "level" of pain? None that I am aware of.

**Question:** Is it possible or likely possible to measure pain scientifically (including assigning some numbers/unit with the same seriousness as length, time, etc.) and build machines doing that with today's technology?

**My starting point:** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain) writes "Pain is a distressing feeling often caused by intense or damaging stimuli." It lists different types of pain: "Nociceptive" (pain is "detected" by sensor cells), "Neuropathic" (pain as damage to the nervous system) and "Psychogenic" (basically emotional pain).

Wikipedia further writes "A person's self-report is the most reliable measure of pain." and quotes Margo McCaffery: "Pain is whatever the experiencing person says it is, existing whenever he says it does". It also has a long [list of pain scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_scales) which are in most cases not further explained. Wikipedia also provided scales for humans that can not communicate pain, e.g. [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_in_babies#Children_and_Infants%E2%80%99_Postoperative_Pain_Scale).

However, I don't want patients telling their pain, but measuring it independently. I image something like this could be archived with brain activity per second or something like that, if there is a pain part in the brain. Wikipedia briefly reports on that too in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain#Physiological_measurement_of_pain). However, the linked FMRI page doesn't contain the word "pain" and the 3 references in the section I just linked are all from 2011 and I'm not a physician, so I dare not to judge if they are affirmative to my question or just wishful thinking. I also don't know if these can measure all three parts of the pain or not. If someone with a medical background could give some evaluation on that point, this would be great. Other insightful answers to the question above are appreciated, too, of course.

**Background, if you need one:** While I think my question above (without looking at my own research and ideas stated thereafter) is specific and general enough to be on-topic here, I'll give some background that brought me to the question in case someone is interested. I insist that this is additional information not needed for answering the question, but some may find it interesting nevertheless. Feel free to edit this part out if it isn't in the spirit of the community.

In my story there is a magic that is defined to inflict the utmost pain possible on individuals, and it is of course regarded evil and forbidden. Then there is this villain (basically evil incarnate) who, as part of that universe, cannot now that this magic is per definition the worst, so he tries to beat it with other means. Cruelty ensues, but the maniac takes a scientific approach and tries to measure just how bad he can be. When the heroes finally stop the villain on his never-ending conquest, just looking at the tip of the iceberg of what he has done disgusts them so much they destroy everything without a second look. The end. (Or is it?)

Sidenote: Of course I can do the measurement magically, but it seems more evil to me if the maniac actually uses scientific methods.

**EDIT:** I decided to move further on-topic discussions to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75710/can-the-level-of-pain-be-measured-on-hold).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical question which belongs on Biology.WB.

Comment: @RonJohn Oh come on! Dyson spheres are technical too but because we don't see how they can be built now, they are on-topic? Is this question really to close to reality to be answered here? I didn't even know that there may be something like this available already, I just found out during my research right before asking, which is more research than many questions show! Additionally, I made it a reality-check, so a yes or no question with follow-up.

Comment: Dyson Spheres are science fiction.  Objective pain measurement... isn't.

Comment: No, pain probably can't be measured objectively, since everyone has a different pain threshold.

Comment: I agree with @RonJohn.  This question isn't about worldbuilding (developing the rules of a world and the societies that live on/in it).  Even if it were a worldbuilding question, since we cannot objectively measure pain today, the answers would be opinion-based, and since the question doesn't focus on a specific kind of pain, too broad.  (Note that I'm not convinced this Q is salvageable.  How would this one, specific issue become the framework for a society or world?)

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't see any *world building* in it.

Comment: This definitely belongs in biology preferably with the neurology tag. You are far more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: However, the answer is "not reliably", and you might want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolorimeter

Comment: @RonJohn Wait, so you are telling me that 1) Objective pain measurement isn't possible and 2) objective pain measurement isn't science fiction? Aren't you contradicting yourself?

Comment: @SK19 no, because "beyond man's reach" doesn't have to imply fiction.

Comment: @RonJohn And how exactly do you know it's "beyond man's reach"? If it is implausible, you possibly can write up why, and that is exactly what I asked this question for.

Comment: @Mołot If you are honestly able to objectively measure pain, this could have an impact on medicine. When you deny the results to the public because they were retrieved in an immoral way, what does this say of your morality. I see a lot of possible world building in it. What is world building for you, exactly?

Comment: @JBH "How would Facebook Sysadmins prevent the summoning of Cthulhu?" and a lot of other high-rated questions here don't seem about developing rules either. Likewise I can argue against your other points. For salvagability, see my answer to Molot.

Comment: Personally, I'm on the fence with this question. Like many others, you seems to ask something that is vaguely related to worldbuilding. Written correctly, almost any question is thinly on topic. That is my resoning and yes sometimes I vote to close questions that remain reopen like "Santa is Satan but why?". While it does seems to be about worldbuilding at all, it is popular and remains open.  Other time I just ignore them when I see them in the review queue because I'M not sure what to do with them.

Comment: Anyway, if a question is not expressly about WB, it is likely to get closed these days. Maybe it is because we have higher standards than before.

Comment: You cannot compare questions asked years ago to today.  Rules change, attitudes toward those rules change.  There are a large number of early questions that would be closed today.  Popularity is not in any way, shape, or form a measure of suitability.  We all go through the process of learning how the rules work and most of us have closed questions (myself included) due to that process.  Welcome to the club.